# Issue getting lazy loading to work with Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Note: I've searched a dozen other related questions regarding lazy loading on SO, but I wasn't able to solve my issue using them.

```
Error: Cannot find 'ContactModule' in 'app/contact.module'
```

I have started with a new project based on Angular CLI and the node console in Windows mentions `webpack: Compiling...` occasionally so I believe I'm using that, however I do not see any webpack.config.js in my project which other questions mentioned needing changes to.

Here's my `app.module.ts`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'contact', loadChildren: 'app/contact.module#ContactModule' },
];

//...imports...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    // ContactComponent,
    // ContactFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My sub module for lazy loading:

```
//...imports...
const ROUTES = [
  { path: '', component: ContactComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ContactComponent,
        ContactFormComponent
    ],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)],
})
class ContactModule {}
```

And some images of my folder structure and packages.json in case those are helpful.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should export your ContactModule:

```
export class ContactModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to figure this out since many of the answers I came across didn't have it in their example...

The lazy loaded module needs to have `export` in the class and `CommonModule` needs to be imported as well as any other things you are using such as forms.